# How to overwrite print in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

Is it possible to rebind print function for IronPython? I rebinded   `__builtins__["print"]` to my custom function but it is not called when `print` is executed.

Comment: Only in the scope of the function? Or globally?

Comment: Is this Python-3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will only work in Python 2 if your program has

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top. And (in Python 2 or Python 3) you don't have to do

```
__builtins__["print"] = my_print_func
```

That is unnecessarily drastic and may have unforeseen side-effects in code you did not write. It is enough to change the definition of `print` in the local namespace, for example

```
print = my_print_func
```